# Display selected item in its listbox

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a list box that has 6 items, and I have coded the listbox to drop down.  My question is, how do I get the selected item to be in the listbox after it's been selected. Here is the code I have in the lostfocus event:

```
'----------------------------------------------------------------
'   Save selection for update query
'----------------------------------------------------------------

 Dim frm As Form, ctl As Control
 Dim varItm As Variant
 Set frm = Forms!loginForm
 Set ctl = frm!areaLB
 For Each varItm In ctl.ItemsSelected
 areaGbl = ctl.ItemData(varItm)
 Next varItm
'----------------------------------------------------------------
'   CHeck selection to load station dropdown
'----------------------------------------------------------------
If areaGbl = "Batting Cages" Then
 Me.stationLB.RowSource = "cageTbl"
 Else
 Me.stationLB.RowSource = "RangeBays"
End If
Me.areaDsp = areaHld
Me.areaLB.Height = 500
```

Comment: Note that I resize the listbox to accomodate only one entry. Me.areaLB.Height = 500. I want the item selected to appearin that listbox.

Comment: Why don't you use a combobox instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is rowsourcetype for areaLB list box control ?

If it's value list, just remove all items and add one record/value from areaGbl variable.

```
For nIndex = 0 To areaLB.ListCount - 1
  areaLB.RemoveItem nIndex
Next nIndex
```

areaLB.AddItem areaGBL

If the rowsourcetype is table/query change the query of rowsource as follows

```
areaLB.rowsource = "Select <fieldName> from <table name> where     
 <fieldname> in '" & areaGBL & "'"
```

Comment: There are six different listboxes, some with value List and others with queries. In your first example, I would have to save the value list and reload it after the listboxes are cleared. Would have to do something similar with second example, save and reload original query. Let me know if my assumptions are correct.  jpl458

Comment: yeah, when clearing or resetting to original. In case of Value list you need original list of values. So declare variables and get the value list before you reset them, so later those can be used when cleared to get original list.It applies to both value list and queries. In case of value list you can use array object to make your work easier.

Comment: I will give it a try.  I understand your code, but it just seems there should be a way in vba to do this.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: the way you are doing is not recommended coding or a best to do solution. showing single value in a list when selected is not a preferred way, rather you may use additional label to display whats been selected etc. Anyway, I had written code as per your requirement.